# npm code-coverage ELIFECYCLE error with phantomjs

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, jasmine, phantomjs

I want to run angular jasmine unit tests on a linux machine.

The error I get is:

```
> ng test --watch=false --code-coverage

[32m26 02 2020 02:44:05.933:INFO [karma-server]: [39mKarma v4.1.0 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
[32m26 02 2020 02:44:05.938:INFO [launcher]: [39mLaunching browsers PhantomJS with concurrency unlimited
[32m26 02 2020 02:44:05.970:INFO [launcher]: [39mStarting browser PhantomJS
[32m26 02 2020 02:44:29.272:INFO [PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0)]: [39mConnected on socket Ew46sEHwaLSfgmQWAAAA with id 52382003
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 0 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
[1A[2KPhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.04 secs / 0 secs)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! my-app@0.0.0 code-coverage: `ng test --watch=false --code-coverage`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the my-app@0.0.0 code-coverage script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

The npm log file is:

```
info it worked if it ends with ok
verbose cli [ '/localdisk/opt/nodejs/node-v10.16.0-linux-x64/bin/node',
verbose cli   '/localdisk/opt/nodejs/current/bin/npm',
verbose cli   'run',
verbose cli   'code-coverage' ]
info using npm@6.9.0
info using node@v10.16.0
verbose run-script [ 'precode-coverage', 'code-coverage', 'postcode-coverage' ]
info lifecycle my-app@0.0.0~precode-coverage: my-app@0.0.0
info lifecycle my-app@0.0.0~code-coverage: my-app@0.0.0
verbose lifecycle my-app@0.0.0~code-coverage: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
verbose lifecycle my-app@0.0.0~code-coverage: PATH: /localdisk/opt/nodejs/node-v10.16.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/localdisk/home/bambooagent/agent1/xml-data/build-dir/my-project/selfportal-ui/node_modules/.bin:/usr/java/jdk1.7/bin:/localdisk/opt/nodejs/current/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin
verbose lifecycle my-app@0.0.0~code-coverage: CWD: /localdisk/home/bambooagent/agent1/xml-data/build-dir/my-project/selfportal-ui
silly lifecycle my-app@0.0.0~code-coverage: Args: [ '-c', 'ng test --watch=false --code-coverage' ]
silly lifecycle my-app@0.0.0~code-coverage: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
info lifecycle my-app@0.0.0~code-coverage: Failed to exec code-coverage script
verbose stack Error: my-app@0.0.0 code-coverage: `ng test --watch=false --code-coverage`
verbose stack Exit status 1
verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/localdisk/opt/nodejs/node-v10.16.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:301:16)
verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:198:13)
verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/localdisk/opt/nodejs/node-v10.16.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
verbose pkgid my-app@0.0.0
verbose cwd /localdisk/home/bambooagent/agent1/xml-data/build-dir/my-project/selfportal-ui
verbose Linux 3.10.0-1062.1.1.el7.x86_64
verbose argv "/localdisk/opt/nodejs/node-v10.16.0-linux-x64/bin/node" "/localdisk/opt/nodejs/current/bin/npm" "run" "code-coverage"
verbose node v10.16.0
verbose npm  v6.9.0
error code ELIFECYCLE
error errno 1
error my-app@0.0.0 code-coverage: `ng test --watch=false --code-coverage`
error Exit status 1
error Failed at the my-app@0.0.0 code-coverage script.
error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

My karma.conf.js is:

```
process.env.CHROME_BIN = require('puppeteer').executablePath();

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-phantomjs-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma'),
    ],
    client: {
      jasmine: {
        random: true,
      },
      clearContext: false, // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, 'coverage'),
      reports: ['html', 'lcovonly'],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true,
    },

    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    customLaunchers: {
      ChromeHeadless: {
       base: 'chrome',
       flags: ['--headless', '--disable-gpu', '--no-sandbox'],
     },
    },
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
    singleRun: true,
  });
};
```

tsconfig.spec.json:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/spec",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "node"
    ],
    "target": "ES5"
  },
  "files": [
    "test.ts",
    "polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

tsconfig.app.json:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "es2015",
    "types": ["node"]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "preserveWhitespaces": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

What could be going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

When using PhantomJS with Angular CLI, make sure that the target bundle syntax is `ES5`, because PhantomJS is not an evergreen browser and doesn't support modern `ES6` syntax.

You can change this by updating your `tsconfig.spec.ts` and add `"target": "ES5"` under `CompilerOptions`.

That being said, if you are looking for a headless browsers, I won't recommend to use PhantomJS for the reasons mentioned above. You should opt to use Chrome Headless instead. More info here: https://angular.io/guide/testing#configure-cli-for-ci-testing-in-chrome

Comment: I have "target": "ES5" in tsconfig.spec.ts, still getting the error. Please see the updated question above